# Woocommerce- Reset product thumbnail size on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having an interesting problem. My thumbnail size for product pages is set to 175 x 169 and for catalog product is 362 x 257 pixels. I am displaying product in header of the shop using this code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[product sku="62-1166"]' );
wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

This is working fine. However on shop pages when this particular product is displayed (one displayed in header) its thumbnail appears to be 362 x 257 pixels rather than 175 x 169 pixels. How to fix this issue?,

Here is demo link: http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/dev/

Ahmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Actually, on further inspection this is due to #product .woocommerce .products li being set as width:90%.

Change this field and that will sort your issue.

```
#product .woocommerce .products li {
width: 175px;
}
```

---

This is being set by the "image-wrap quickview" div class. It has the max width of 362px.

If you edit the CSS to give .image-wrap.quickview a max-width of 175px, then your product thumbnail will display the correct width.

```
.image-wrap.quickview {
max-width: 175px;
}
```

This will also reduce the size of the thumbnails in the related products below.

Alternatively, you can change the default thumbnail sizes in the WooCommerce settings page under Catalog. Scroll down to the end and change "Single Product Image". After doing this, regenerate your thumbnails with the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin.

Comment: Hello but why this width has been applied to other products?

Comment: See my edit above the line break. This should apply the settings to just that one item.